# App is freezing when I move the window in OS X 10.9

Tags: osx-mavericks

I am working on an app that has no problem running on previous versions of OS X. On 10.9, the app works fine except when I try moving the app window, at which point it freezes and I have to stop it.

Where could I find some information about why this is happening with OS X 10.9, and how I could fix it?

I'm using Xcode 4.6.3, in case that’s relevant.

Comment: Are you tracking window movement notifications (`NSWindowWillMoveNotification ` etc.)?

Comment: Hello?  Anyone there?

Comment: NO. I am not using any window movement notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently, other users have been complaining about experiencing freezing symptom on OS X 10.9 and so am I.

### One possible solution:

Try restarting your OS X. If it freezes to death, you need to hold Power button until it completely turns off itself. Then you can press Power button again to turn on your machine.

Before the grey bootup screen appears, hold keys **[Command]+[Option]+[P]+[R]** immediately til your machine reboots again and release keys to go for normal booting process.

You'll notice both screen brightness and sound volume return to the default level. This resets the PRAM for Macbook in most case. You may need to repeat these steps if your OS X freeze again next time.

People are waiting for the next update and suggest leaving one of the culprits, the Wi-Fi feature, ON at all time to avoid possible freezing symptom.